# In Jupyter notebook/lab, how can I automatically reset variables on exit?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a jupyter notebook containing sensitive data that I would like to not be cached inside the notebook. This would avoid jupyter's tendency to mix data and code.

In a notebook I can reset all variables using

`%reset`

Is there any way to run this automatically on exit, or on shutdown of the notebook or server?

Or is there a command-line script that could be run over a `.ipynb`, e.g. in a nightly cron job, to purge the file of stored variables (or - even better - only certain variables)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[nbclean](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html) allows some fairly complex customization on what gets cleaned and altered in the resulting notebook. You could do cron job with a script running that on your schedule. Or use Github actions to trigger upon actions such as push.